# How can I run the Bitcoin client on Natty?

Tags: 11.04, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Bitcoin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41001/how-do-i-install-bitcoin)

The ppa:stretch/bitcoin-ppa doesn't have any packages, as I can see, and when I download the tar.gz from sourceforge that (the official client) it just wont start. Is there any dependencies I've missed, or what?