# How to run the official bitcoin client?

Tags: unity, bitcoin

I want to run the *official* Bitcoin client, rather than one from somebody's Personal PPA, as was explained in Question [41001](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41001/how-do-i-install-bitcoin).

How do I install and run it?