# How to install Bitcoin mining software?

Tags: bitcoin

I see there's an [existing question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41001/how-do-i-install-bitcoin) on how to install the Satoshi Bitcoin client, but I'm wanting to install mining software.

Like the asker of the above question, I'm new to Ubuntu, so I'm not familiar with the process of installing software if it's not in the package manager.

I've got a ATI 5770 card which I've previously used with the Pheonix miner, so that will likely be the best mining software to use. It's [available here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=75786), but I'm not sure what to do with it now that I've downloaded it.

Answer (score 4):

First, the website says that the package depends on Python, twisted, and PyOpenCL. Python is probably already installed. However to make sure, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python python-twisted python-pyopencl
```

You'll need to enter your root password.

Now, download the Source Code/Linux Release. You'll get a tarball, which is basically a package containing all the source files. Next, you need to untar (unpack) it. Use the following command:

```
tar xzf filename.tar.gz
```

where `filename.tar.gz` is the file you downloaded, which in this case is `phoenix2-phoenix-v2.0.0-rc2-9-g2c83ee6.tar.gz`.

After unpacking, it will create a folder containing the source files (in this case, `phoenix2-phoenix-2c83ee6`). Move into the folder using

```
cd phoenix2-phoenix-2c83ee6
```

Simply use the following command, and it'll take care of everything:

```
./setup.py
```

Note: If the installation fails, this might be due to unmet dependencies. In such a case, install the dependencies and try again.

Comment: ./setup.py returned this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` and try again.

Comment: did any of this work?

Comment: setup.py needs an argument. I don't know what that would be though.