# I need a bitcoin miner, and how to install it?

Tags: bitcoin

I have attempted to follow [the tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176025/how-to-install-bitcoin-mining-software?rq=1), and got this:

```
deathd@ubuntu:~$ cd phoenix2-phoenix-2c83ee6
deathd@ubuntu:~/phoenix2-phoenix-2c83ee6$ ./setup.py
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

I followed the part at the bottom of the page, and received this:

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: error processing alsa-base (--configure):
 package alsa-base is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 alsa-base
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I've read that, and it fails.
deathd@ubuntu:~/phoenix2-phoenix-2c83ee6$ ./setup.py
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied

Comment: Sorry :P

I start by doing the first part, and here is the Terminal log:

Comment: Ok, updated question. Sorry :)

Comment: Going to sleep. Turning of Ubuntu, and switching back to Windows to Mine Bitcoins for the night. Hopefully I will have a answer in the morning.

Comment: Did you try installing using a PPA? Like this one, https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin?

Comment: @DeathD Thanks for updating your question. Go ahead and delete your comments when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look here because there might be a better client and read through all of them. If your mining on a cpu it won't really matter, but any gpu you should seriously consider the software before you mine. Also you should find instructions on the wiki on how to install if not just seek the program homepage by a google search I usually * how to install where *= name of BTC program

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Software