# How do I build Bitcoin from source on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, source, makefile, bitcoin, autotools

(Using Autotools) I have downloaded the Bitcoin source from "Bitcoin Core Version 0.9.1" When I input the following command `./autogen.sh` it produces the following warning:

```
includes' is the old name for 'am_cppflags' (or '*_cppflags').
```

When I attempt `./configure` I get the following error message:

```
configure: error: found berkley DB other than 4.8, required for 
portable wallets ( --with-incompatible-bdb to ignore).
```

And lastly, when I input `make` I get the output of:

```
make: * No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

Comment: If you are missing the '.' in `./autogen.sh` that might be a problem. (The commands you wrote above are to build bitcoin-qt) Make sure you have all the dependencies. You will also need to build berkley DB and a couple other things. The instructions are here : https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md Check through this, because it looks like a lot of things could break "Ubuntu 12.04 and later have packages for libdb5.1-dev and libdb5.1++-dev, but using these will break binary wallet compatibility, and is not recommended." Things like that. tl;dr Get ALL the dependencies.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I typed the command in properly

Comment: Did you make sure all the dependencies were ok? There seems to be a lot you have to build to get this complete (if you want a full compile from source).

Comment: Yes, I have installed all the dependencies. I followed the build doc instructions and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Did you try the compile instructions at [How do I install Bitcoin?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41001/how-do-i-install-bitcoin)?